# Posible traducción/adaptación del título de "Ghost in the Shell"

Tags: traducción, españa

Desde que se lanzó la primera película de *[Ghost in the Shell](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113568/?ref_=nv_sr_2)* allá por el año 1995, a veces los aficionados al anime hemos tratado de buscar cuál podría ser una posible traducción o adaptación de dicho título.

El título hace referencia a la posibilidad de que una máquina que, en principio debería ser un cascarón vacío lleno simplemente con una determinada programación, comience a mostrar signos de estar realmente viva, y por tanto desarrollar un "alma".

Con la llegada de la adaptación en imagen real, aquí en España estamos viendo en los carteles precisamente ese subtítulo como posible adaptación:

> El alma de la máquina

Sin embargo, dicha adaptación me parece bastante fría, y pierde el sentido como de "espectro" o más bien "presencia inesperada", "presencia difícil de intuir pero que parece que algo hay ahí", encerrado en una carcasa vacía, dado que dicho subtítulo parece dar por sentado que la máquina ya tiene un alma.

Partiendo de traducciones literales como "el fantasma en la concha" (saludos a los Hispanoamericanos que se están partiendo de risa ahora mismo) o "el espectro en la cáscara", me gustaría poder llegar a alguna traducción o adaptación que mantenga esa sutileza del título original, y que al mismo tiempo suene novelera (vamos, que suene bien, no forzada). ¿Cuál podría ser esa versión más fiel al original?

Comment: Bueno, lo más fiel sería «Policía antidisturbios blindada con movilidad»

Comment: @guifa no lo pillo. :-(

Comment: el título original viene del japonés

Comment: @guifa vale, leñe, no lo había pillado. Al parecer el título original es 攻殻機動隊 (Kōkaku Kidōtai), que se traduce más o menos como dices. Sin embargo el manga original tiene como subtítulo "The Ghost in the Shell", como se puede ver [en la Wikipedia en inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell_(manga)). El segundo manga tuvo como subtítulo "Man-machine interface". Lo que pasó fue que el subtítulo "Ghost in the Shell" se quedó como nombre para toda la obra fuera de Japón. Como pasó con "Juego de tronos", que a pesar de ser el título del primer libro se usa para toda la serie de TV.

Comment: Sería ingenioso, copiar "El fantasma de la opera" pero pierde mucho significado: "El fantasma de la ostra" :-)

Comment: En mi país usan las traducciones más inverosímiles y ridículas para los títulos de buenas películas. "Mi vecino es un extraterrestre" (district 9) viene a la mente. No me extrañaría que tradujeran el título "Ghost I the shell" como "aventuras de una chica autómata en el país del futuro " :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema para encontrar una traducción es que ambos sustantivos del subtítulo original en inglés son polisémicos y bastante ricos en asociaciones diversas, por lo cual inevitablemente se pierde algo no importa cómo se traduzca.

En efecto, *ghost* significa "fantasma" hoy, pero hasta no hace demasiado tiempo significaba también "espíritu"; de ahí que "Espíritu Santo" se dijera *Holy Ghost* y que existiese como sinónimo de "morir" la expresión *[give up the ghost](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_up_the_ghost)* (algo así como "abandonar/dejar ir el espíritu").

Por otro lado, *shell* significa "concha, cascarón", refiriéndose tanto a moluscos como a las cáscaras duras de frutas y similares, pero en informática [el mismo término](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)) se refiere a una interfaz de usuario (generalmente una interfaz de línea de comandos o "consola").

El título *Ghost in the Shell* hace referencia a la expresión *ghost in the machine*, que describe la idea dualista cartesiana de que existe un fantasma, espíritu o entidad no material que habita dentro del cuerpo material y lo dirige como si fuese una máquina. El uso de *shell* juega con estos significados: la *shell* es el exterior mecánico que envuelve un sistema cuyas profundidades íntimas son de otra manera inaccesibles.

*El alma de la máquina* no me parece una mala traducción; *El alma **en** la máquina* sería más acertado pero no suena bien en castellano; *Interfaz humano-máquina* se acercaría más todavía pero ningún productor aceptaría semejante cosa como título.

Comment: Pues no te creas, "el alma en la máquina" me suena bastante bien. Un simple cambio de preposición y de repente se recuperan bastantes de las connotaciones perdidas. ¡Bien visto!

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Si te parece bien, a mí también. Sólo digo que es poco común esa construcción en castellano (al contrario que en inglés). En japonés existe la posibilidad muy *cool* de transformar con una simple partícula un complemento adverbial ("en la máquina") en un genitivo que se aplica directamente a un sustantivo; no así en castellano, donde haría falta para mayor claridad una subordinada.

Comment: +1 por lo de consola

Answer (score 2):

I looked it up in Wikipedia.  I can't say I understood what I read there, but I did see something about prosthetics.  It gave me a bit of the feeling of the Tin Woodman in the book *The Wizard of Oz*, where through a series of accidents, each body part of the woodman has to be replaced by tin.  The Tin Woodman, until the Wizard gives him a symbolic heart, believes that he is just a shell of a man, and that the heart he used to have, when he was flesh and blood, is missing.  So here's my proposal (probably no good, but I offer it to further the discussion):

> El Alma Fantasma en el Cuerpo-Coraza

What I want to convey is that there are two problems, one, that the body parts aren't original, and two, that whatever is occupying that strange shell of a body is more of a ghost than a true soul.

Comment: That's a very interesting point, and a good reference to _The Wizard of Oz_, I hadn't thought that the Tin Man was a similar case. The translation doesn't sound good as is, but _[coraza](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AoXZDhy)_ could be a good adaptation for _shell_, so _El fantasma en la coraza_ could be a nice choice.

Answer (score 1):

Interesante pregunta. Yo veo complicado encontrar una traducción en pocas palabras que recoja los matices del original, sobre todo la palabra *shell* y su significado de "caparazón/concha/coraza" y el de "interfaz de usuario"como indicaba @pablodf76. En español no tenemos una palabra así.

A mi sinceramente me gusta mucho más *El alma **en** la máquina* que *El alma **de** la máquina*, creo que le da una profundidad diferente a la frase, como algo vivo que habitara la máquina y no simplemente algo que está ahí (es mi impresión).

El lugar de *ghost* podría usarse [espíritu](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GcX069Y) que es una palabra con muchos matices *El espíritu en la máquina* podría también ser una opción aunque creo que ya se ha usado en alguna otra ocasión para otros proyectos que nada tienen que ver.

Otra opción sería [ánima](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2gpyqUS), una palabra con varios matices interesantes también aunque con una carga negativa en el imaginario colectivo bastante importante.

Sin traducir tan literalmente podríamos usar palabras como *esencia* o *conciencia*.

Volviendo a *shell* creo que máquina está bien aunque no signifique para nada lo mismo, pero la idea que transmite sirve perfectamente. No me convencen palabras como coraza, armazón, caparazón, etc. pero si me gusta *interfaz* usando el otro significado de *shell*.

Con todo esto puedo hacer varias combinaciones a gusto del consumidor:

- El ánima en la máquina
- La esencia en la máquina
- La conciencia de la interfaz
- El espíritu en la interfaz